# How to create a procedure in oracle 10g to fetch an entire row

Tags: oracle10g

I am trying to make a procedure, Which will take the employee id as input and fetch me an entire row with 7 columns.  However, I have created a procedure but when i run it, it gives an error stating "invalid identifier". please tell me what am i doing wrong ?

```
   create or replace procedure getdetails (empid number) 
   is 
    stmt varchar2 (1000);
    begin
    stmt :='select  * from myadmin where employe_id=empid';
    execute immediate stmt;
    end;
    /
```

executing using below statement

```
begin getdetails (5); 
end;


     package pack.java;
     import pack.java.allrequestmodel;
     import java.io.*;
     import java.lang.*;
     import java.sql.*;
     import javax.servlet.*;
     import javax.servlet.http.*;
     import javax.servlet.jsp.*;
     import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;

         public class allrequestcontrol extends TagSupport
       {
       HttpServletRequest request;
       HttpServletResponse response;
       String ss="";
       String emp="";
       public int doStartTag() throws JspException
       {
            request=(HttpServletRequest)pageContext.getRequest();
            response=(HttpServletResponse)pageContext.getResponse();
        return EVAL_PAGE;
        }

        public ResultSet check()
        {           
        HttpSession mysession=request.getSession();
         ss=(String)mysession.getAttribute("user");
         mysession.setAttribute("user",ss);
      JspWriter out=pageContext.getOut();
      Connection con;
      CallableStatement stmt;
      ResultSet rs=null;
          try
        {
       Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        }
        catch( ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
        }
          try
        {

 con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","gaurav","oracle");
        stmt=con.prepareCall("call getdetails(?)");
        stmt.setString(1,ss);
        rs=stmt.executeQuery();
       }
        catch(SQLException ex)
       {
       }

        return rs;
       } 

         public int doEndTag() throws JspException
       {

        JspWriter out=pageContext.getOut();
        ResultSet rs= check();
        try
      {
      out.println("<table border=2>");
      out.println("<tr>");
      out.println("<th>EmployeId</th>");
      out.println("<th>Supervisor</th>");
      out.println("<th>Department</th>");
      out.println("<th>PickDate.</th>");
      out.println("<th>PickTime</th>");
      out.println("<th>DropDate</th>");
      out.println("<th>DropTime</th>");
      out.println("<th>Status</th>");
      out.println("<th></th>");
      out.println("</tr>");
      while(rs.next())
     {
     out.println("<tr>");
     out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(1)+"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(2)+"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(3)+"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(4)+"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(5)+"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(6)+"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(7)+"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+rs.getString(8)+"</td>");
     out.println("<td><input type=radio name=radio value="+rs.getString(8)+"></td>");
    out.println("</tr>");
   }
   emp=(String)request.getParameter("radio");
   HttpSession mysession=request.getSession();
   mysession.setAttribute("deleteemp",emp);
  }
   catch(Exception ex)
  {
  }

   return super.doEndTag();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using Dynamic SQL?

Comment: You need to select `into` something.

Comment: Actually am new to PL/SQL, so am self learning.  I am confused on whether to use a function or a procedure to fetch an entire row ??
and as u suggested i need to select into something, i dont know how to go about it because i tried using "dual" it doesnt allow

Comment: The PL/SQL documentation is very bad -- too fragmented -- IMHO, but this might be the best page for you: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm#sthref3044

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL allows you to use SQL directly, you don't need dynamic SQL (execute immediate) in this case.

Also, you can select an entire row into a ROWTYPE variable, which will be a record type taking the same structure as the row in the table. For example:

```
procedure getdetails (empid number) 
is 
  my_rec myadmin%ROWTYPE;
begin
  select *
  INTO my_rec
  from myadmin
  where employe_id=empid;
  -- now you can refer to my_rec.employe_id, etc.
end;
```

Comment: Thanks.  Also ,i am calling this procedure through JDBC (Have updated the code above) to display the row associated with a particular (empid) but  the code doesnt display anything. please tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: you need to do something with the returned record - e.g. use OUT parameters to return the results to the calling process.